# How do I set probability thresholds for a logistic regression and cutoffs in randomForest model to get a good confusion matrix?

Tags: r, random-forest, logistic, confusion-matrix

Whenever I run a logistic regression, I need to set the threshold so that it groups probabilities higher than the threshold to my positive group:

```
table(test$Noshow, logpred>0.5)
```

What I sometimes do is to optimize my confusion matrix so that I get a good Sensitivity and Specificity values. Is this a good way to do it?

On the other hand, when I run a randomForest model using the "randomForest" package, I can set the cutoffs such as this:

```
k <- 0.5
rfcutoff <- c(k, 1-k)
rftree <- randomForest(rffrmla_all, data = train1, mtry = 2, keep.forest = TRUE, importance = TRUE, ntree = 500, cutoff = rfcutoff)
```

Again I optimize my confusion matrix to get a good cutoff or base the cutoff on a naive baseline proportion. What is a good way to do this?

Comment: These are not really programming questions, these are questions about statistical models. If you need statistical help, you should post to [stats.se], not Stack Overflow. Maybe look at ROC plots to look at trade-offs between sensitivity and specificity.